# Разновидности реализаций языка Python

Tags: python, дизайн-языка

В любой книге, где бы я не читал, говорится, что есть различные реализации языка.   Стандартный это, как я знаю, *CPython*, а есть еще и другие (*JPython*, *IronPython*).

Не могу понять, ведь у других реализаций интерпритаторов должен быть свой специфичный синтаксис?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Разницы в синтаксисе нет — каждый интерпретатор должен поддерживать [грамматику Питона](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), чтобы иметь право называться таковым. Разница между интерпретаторами есть в

- скорости выполнения кода,
- доступности модулей: к примеру, не все модули стандартной библиотеки, что имплементированы в CPython, доступны в других реализациях, или имеют другую имплементацию. Модули, которые имплементируют часть функционала в С ("C extensions"), чаще всего не доступны ни с одним другим интерпретатором, кроме CPython'а (к примеру, сторонних реализаций `numpy`/`scipy` нигде, кроме как для PyPy, нет, да и там она добавлена практически вчера и в бете, ЕМНИП),
- мостиках в другие языки. К примеру, Jython умеет напрямую импортировать Java-классы - такой код кинет `ImportError` в других интерпретаторах:

  ```
  from java.util import Date
  from java.lang import System

  d = Date()
  System.out.println(d)
  ```

  Точно так же IronPython умеет работать с CLR и .NЕТ:

  ```
  from System import DateTime, String
  d = DateTime.Now
  print String.Format("{0}", d)
  ```

Comment: Вы властелин), глаза открываете мгновенно), спасибо вам огромное, хотелось бы к вам на подаваны))

Comment: Рад был помочь! Я на самом деле так, средненького пошиба; тут есть настоящие гуру питона, мне с ними не тягаться.

Comment: Вроде бы должно быть `DateTime.Now`, а не `DateTime.now`?

Comment: @qwertiy точно, благодарю! Исправил.

Answer (score 4):

Язык задан описанием синтаксиса и грамматики и он, в общем случае, абстрактен.

Реализация языка позволяет переводить код на языке в код, понятный процессору, чтобы он его мог выполнить.

Реализации языка не отличаются в плане синтаксиса, но могут отличаться в плане семантики конструкций. Посмотрите, например, известное выражение `i++ + ++i`.

Каждый интерпретатор понимает один и тот же код на Питоне, но переводит его в машинные коды немного по разному.

Comment: Известное выражение - это же не `Python`, как я понял?

Comment: Это выражение иллюстрирует проблемы и неоднозначности реализации языка.